# A homomorphism induces a continuous map from ${\rm Spec}(A') \to {\rm Spec}(A)$.

Tags: general-topology, ring-theory

Let $A, A'$ be commutative rings with $1 \neq 0$.  Let $h : A \to A'$ be such that $h(1) = 1$.  Then $f: {\rm Spec}(A') \to {\rm Spec}(A)$ defined by $f(\mathfrak{p}') = h^{-1}(\mathfrak{p}')$ is continous with respect to the spectral topologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The ideal you're looking for is $\mathfrak b' = \mathfrak a^e$ where $\mathfrak a^e$ (the *extension* of $\mathfrak a$) is the ideal in $A'$ generated by $h(\mathfrak a)$.

Now that you know what the other side should be, showing that $f^{-1}V(\mathfrak a) = V(\mathfrak a^e)$ isn't too bad.  Just do both inclusions separately.

Comment: How did they guess $\mathfrak{a}^e$ was the correct one?  Perhaps you can derive?

Comment: You need an ideal in $A'$ whose definition should depend on the ideal $\mathfrak a$.  Well... there's really only one way to turn $\mathfrak a$ into an ideal of $A'$ so either that way is gonna work or the theorem probably isn't true.

Comment: So $h(\mathfrak{a})$ isn't necc. an ideal?

Comment: When $h$ is not surjective.  For example if $h\colon k[x] \to k[x, y]$ is the obvious inclusion and $\mathfrak a = (x)$ is the ideal generated by $x$ then $h(\mathfrak a)$ is not closed under multiplication by $y$.

Answer (score 2):

Your question follows from the following:

- If $I$ is an ideal in $A$, then $I \subset I^{ec}$.
- If $J$ is an ideal in $A'$, then $J^{ce} \subset J$.

These facts can be proved easily from the definition of contracted and extended ideals.

Now, let $I$ be an ideal in $A$. Let $\mathfrak p \in f^{-1}(V(I))$. We have $I \subset \mathfrak p^c$; hence $I^e \subset \mathfrak p^{ce} \subset \mathfrak p$. Thus, $\mathfrak p \in V(I^e)$.

Conversely, if $\mathfrak p \in V(I^e)$, then $I^e \subset \mathfrak p$; hence $I^{ec} \subset \mathfrak p^c$. Since $I \subset I^{ec}$, it follows that $\mathfrak p \in f^{-1}(V(I))$.

Therefore $f^{-1}(V(I)) = V(I^e)$ and $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Jim.  I've got it now.  $f^{-1} V(\mathfrak{a}) = \{ \mathfrak{p}' \in {\rm Spec(A')} : f(\mathfrak{p}') \in V(\mathfrak{a}) \equiv h^{-1}\mathfrak{p}' \in V(\mathfrak{a}) \equiv \exists \mathfrak{p} \in V(\mathfrak{a}) : h(\mathfrak{p}) = \mathfrak{p}'\} \subset V((h(\mathfrak{a}))$

since $\mathfrak{p} \supset \mathfrak{a} \implies h(\mathfrak{p}) = \mathfrak{p}' \supset (h(\mathfrak{a}))$.  The opposite inclusion can be shown more easily.